# how to solve a linear pde of changing evolution equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, linear-pde

i would like to solve a a second order PDE with joint evolution. what i mean is that before time v, it follows a pde and when the time is greater than v, it follows another linear pde. what i concern the most is eliminate the killing rate after time v. are there any corresponding reference for it?

Comment: It would help to provide an example problem. This will probably help you get some more feedback.

Comment: Please write the equations using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/418542), i.e. write maths inside `$` symbols using appropriate markups.